# catchError cancel all parallel requests

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I made multiple requests in parallel. then I throw error when timeout.

```
getAllDirections() {
...
return from(urls).pipe( // a list of api urls
  mergeMap((urlParam, index) =>
    this.http.get<ISchedules>(urlParam[0]).pipe(
      map(dataRes => {
        return dataRes;
      }),
      timeout(6000),
      catchError(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return throwError(`Request timeout ${error}`);
      })
    )
  )
);
```

Then in my effect I capture the error

```
$LoadSchedulingsByDirectionsByBranch = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<any>(ESchedulesActions.Type..),
    mergeMap(action =>
      this.apiCallsService.getAllDirections(action.payload, '2010-09-18').pipe(
        map(trips => ({
          type: ESchedulesActions.TypeSuccess,
          payload: trips
        })),
        catchError(err => {
          console.log(err);
          return of({
            type: ESchedulesActions.TypeFail,
            payload: err
          });
        })
      )
    )
  )
);
```

the issue is that when it detect **the first** timeout the mergeMap **stops** and don't treat other calls.
As a result I get only one `console.log(error)`  of instead having error on every http request. ( get inside `catchError` only one time )

On my http network devtools I notice that all the parallel requests are canceled when the first timeout occur.

Comment: does it work if you don't do a catchError in `getAllDirections`? Just wondering, it looks okay to me so far...

Comment: Same, it seems that `catchError` "kill"  the all actual requests

Comment: Actually, `throwError` kills the source. You can try it - `return of ('Request timeout ${error}')`  and source will stay alive. When you return an error, it bubbles up to the error callback and closes the stream.

Comment: @dev I think second `catchError` was meant to catch the bubbled error. I am just wondering wether it actually receives the error. I think if he simply will return `of( ... )` then it will not get into second `catchError` for sure but will be processed by `map` operator

Comment: @dev Great ! thanks very much

Comment: Ur welcome. @Blind Despair - first catchError kills it

Comment: Sorry I notice that the second catchError in my effect don't catch the return  from the service :/

Comment: @infodev but that's what I mean, if you just do a return `of( ... )` then there is nothing more for second catchError to catch, because there is no more error.

Comment: So how can I catch the return of the service function inside the effect ? I need to run an action for every fail

Comment: I'll submit another question because it's another problem

Comment: problem is that you have a single internal stream and if you rethrow the error that stream dies, what you can do however is to create list of streams. A stream per each url instead of doing `from(urls)` you can map them to individual streams, then when each of those dies it will be caught by catchError in effect

Comment: Ok I see beter now , but how to create individual streams