# catchError kill the steam of parallel requets

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have service that calls Api urls in parallel.

Then I would catch url errors ( server error, timeout , ect )

```
getAllDirections() {
...
return from(urls).pipe( // a list of api urls
  mergeMap((urlParam, index) =>
    this.http.get<ISchedules>(urlParam[0]).pipe(
      map(dataRes => {
        return dataRes;
      }),
      timeout(6000),
      catchError(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return throwError(`Request timeout ${error}`);
      })
    )
  )
);
```

the issue is that when it detect **the first** timeout the mergeMap **stops** and don't treat other calls.
`throwError()` kill the stream or urls.

I would like to know how can I create multiple streams so that when an error occur on one url, the service keep treat other urls ?

**Update**

Actually I'm able to use `of`  instead of `throwError`  but I'll not be able to catch error in the parent listener ( ngrx effect ) the result will be consumed by `map`  instead. That's not a good practice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [catchError cancel all parallel requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59953249/catcherror-cancel-all-parallel-requests)

Comment: It's slitly different, this treat one single stream ( using From ) , I would do that with multi streams to be able to use throwError

Comment: what do you want to happen if 1 request times out, but the others do not timeout?

Comment: I would continu to wait for other until timeout occur for them or also api error happens

Comment: . every api request have it's state on my store , so I have to set failure state of every http request. actually if one timeout occur , the observable stops and only the state of concerned api timeout is updated and not the others